# Doctrine Querybuilder ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following query builder:

```
$queryBuilder = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('recipient')
    ->leftJoin('recipient.message', 'message')
    ->orderBy('message.dateSent', 'DESC');
```

This has been working fine :) - but since upgrading to `Mysql 5.7` I have started getting this error everywhere:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]:
>   General error: 3065
>   Expression #1 of `ORDER BY` clause is not in `SELECT` list, references column `'dctrn_result.date_sent_5'` which is not in `SELECT` list;
>   this is incompatible with `DISTINCT`

I have solved this in most places where I am using the `DBAL` layer by just add the item to the select list, but I can't figure out how to do that with this particular `queryBuilder`.

Comment: One solution I found and also worked for me is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40000429/572801)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to edit the `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf` by adding these lines:

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode=""
```

Don't forget to restart the service mysql:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

For info, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 16):

Adding:

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode=""
```

to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` fixed the problem for me (after restarting service). Although of course an official response to the [doctrine issue](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5622) would be nicer.

Update: Someone who knows more than me about this [recommended only disabling the mode that's causing the problem.](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5622#issuecomment-231727355)

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug reported in [#4846](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4846) and it seems to be related to [#sqlmode_only_full_group_by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) and there are some examples abaut what does it mean [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). Until a proper fix comes out a solution would be to add `->addSelect('message')` to the query (I don't know if it fixes the issue or doctrine rewrites the query anyway), but that way doctrine will hydrate massages as well which maybe not desired or disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql mode, but then, mysql maybe can return invalid data.

Answer (score 3):

Actually mysql 5.7 contains '***ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY***' in sql mode.So we can't perform orderby in the element that is not in select list.we have to change it from

```
'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

into

```
'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

We can done this by executing the following queries

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

Thanks,

Suriya

Answer (score 0):

When using `QueryBuilder`, joined tables are not added to the select list automatically. You can call `addSelect(TABLE_ALIAS)` to get rid of the error.

```
$queryBuilder = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('recipient')
    ->leftJoin('recipient.message', 'message')
    ->addSelect('message') //THIS LINE
    ->orderBy('message.dateSent', 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating Doctrine to 2.8 should resolve this.