# SQL get rows based on two ids

Tags: mysql, select

I really don't know how to title this problem properly.

Heres the table structure:

```
ID | CLIENT_ID | …
```

`ID` is primary and auto increment. `CLIENT_ID` on the other hand can occur multiple times.

What i want is to fetch the rows by `CLIENT_ID` with highest `ID` ... Heres a example

```
ID | CLIENT_ID
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 2
4  | 3
5  | 2
```

So here `CLIENT_ID` 1 and 2 occurs multiple times (because there is a newer version).

After the query i want the following `ID`s in the results: 2,4,5 (Because the highest `ID` in rows with `CLIENT_ID` 1 is the row with `ID` 2 and so on)

Comment: Look here  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

And i think this is pointing you in the right direction:
SELECT outer.* FROM tableName AS outer LEFT OUTER JOIN tableName as inner ON outer.id = inner.id AND outer.client_id < inner.client_id WHERE inner.id IS NULL;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need all the columns you can use a select in

```
 select * from my_table 
 where (id, client_id) in ( select max(id), client_id 
                            from my_table 
                            group by client_id);
```

but if you need only the id

```
 select id  from my_table 
 where (id, client_id) in ( select max(id), client_id 
                            from my_table 
                            group by client_id);
```

or more simple

```
   select max(id) 
   from my_table 
   group by client_id;
```

Comment: Man thats amazing ;) i never had figured this out on my own

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY client_id HAVING max(id)
```

this should be more efficient than a sub select

Comment: Looks great ... nice and clean. But i get the following error: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'xyz.properties.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Ok is just run set sql_mode = '' directly after the db connect like mentioned here and it works now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23921234/2593099

Comment: Hmm looks like i still doesn't work correctly. It returns wrong fields.

Comment: What is it returning?  As scarisEdge pointed out, you could specify the fields in the select.  So `SELECT table.id, table.client_id FROM table GROUP BY client_id HAVING max(table.id)`

Comment: Looks like the HAVING is applied after the grouping. I got table rows like this 1|1, 2|1 and 3|2 but as return i get 1 and 3

Comment: Ah, the last block in @scarisEdge's answer is probably the way to go then.

Comment: The first it is because i want to select *. Nevertheless thank you for your time ;)