# How to set global and session mode in my.cnf

Tags: mysql

[Following this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by), I have to set global and session as followings when I restart mysql, 
How can I set this in my.cnf?

```
mysql> set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
mysql> set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
mysql> exit;
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: My localhost Server version: 5.7.9 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score 0):

From the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html):

```
[mysqld] 
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Comment: I tried it. I restarted mysql but it does not reflect what I put it in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ! to the beginning of the line,

```
!sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```