# Select list contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1055

Since updating MySQL I've noticed the following query fails

```
SELECT u.*, p.name as plan, COUNT(u.id) as totalprojects FROM users u LEFT JOIN plans p ON p.id = access LEFT JOIN maps m ON m.user_id = u.id WHERE u.email = 'john@doe.com'
```

> In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list
>   contains nonaggregated column 'kontakt.u.id'; this is incompatible
>   with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Does anyone know how to get this query fixed to sort the error?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by

Comment: @ChrisLear I tried this method but after I restart mysql it still doesn't work. I also tried editing my .cnf file but mysql fails to restart / start afterwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Node server with Digital Ocean the conference file I needed to edit was located `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Adding in the following

```
[mysqld] sql_mode = "NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

And then `service mysql restart` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 7):

the easiest solution is ANY_VALUE function:
[ANY_VALUE official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value)

```
SELECT name, ANY_VALUE(address), MAX(age) FROM t GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of two things:

1) change your query so that everything in the select clause is aggregated. Something like this

```
SELECT u.email, p.name as plan, COUNT(u.id) as totalprojects FROM users u LEFT JOIN plans p ON p.id = access LEFT JOIN maps m ON m.user_id = u.id WHERE u.email = 'john@doe.com' group by u.email;
```

2) Change the sql mode to allow mysql to run your query. Something like this

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = "NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

in your my.cnf file.

Note that this sets various sql_mode options. You can read about them here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: When I try Step 2 mysql won't restart or start. It's a Node server running on Ubuntu