# groupBy does not work properly for eloquent and query builder in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a simple `Education` model contains these fields:

```
e_id // Primary key
user_id //foreign key to link to User model
field
grade
university
country_education
city_education
date_of_graduation
```

And this is my Model structure:

```
class Education extends Model
    {
        public    $primaryKey = 'e_id';
        public    $timestamps = false;
        protected $table      = 'educations';

        protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'field', 'grade', 'university', 'country_education', 'city_education', 'date_of_graduation'];

        public function user ()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'user_id');
        }

    }
```

Now I want to select distinct rows based on `user_id` field. to that I wrote this:

```
$educations = Education::select(['e_id', 'user_id', 'field', 'grade'])->groupBy(['user_id']);
```

But below error is occured :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'lms_forms.educations.e_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `e_id`, `user_id`, `field`, `grade` from `educations` group by `user_id` limit 10 offset 0)
```

then I added `e_id` primary key to `groupBy(['user_id'])` :

```
$educations = Education::select(['e_id', 'user_id', 'field', 'grade'])->groupBy(['user_id','e_id']);
```

Query runs but return all records regardless of `user_id` distinction.

What is Problem and What can I do ?

Comment: MYSQL5.7 has made some changes in this area check the migration note https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-migration.html You really should read ALL the error message that MYSQ provides, the clue is in the error message

Comment: What do you want to select? Distinct user? I guess a user may have multiple fields/grades?

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche,district educations for each user means select just one education for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode switched on (it is by default set to ON on MySql 5.7+).

This is an improvement done on latest mysql version to avoid removal of rows from the query result. Instead of grouping it with PK, try grouping it with other columns to return proper results.

Or else Disable this mode if you just want to proceed with the results

See - [Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by)

Comment: when I do not include PK in groupBy() , that error shown. Because of this I have to add PK to grouping. and then query runs but return all records and grouping does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ... In folder **config** => **database.php** make sure mysql **strict** is ***false***, like this

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

if strict is true,  make it false then clear config cash by run this command in cmd

> php artisan config:clear