# CakePHP3: SELECT list is not in GROUP BY in belongsToMany association

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.3

I already encountered such problem but I don't understand how to define `group()` in this case:

I have the following tables:

```
Articles {
    'id',
    'name',
}

Categories {
    'id',
    'name'
}

ArticlesCategories {
    'article_id',
    'category_id'
}
```

And the query is:

```
$seconds = $this->Categories->find()
->contain([
    'Articles' => function ($q) {
        return $q->distinct(['Articles.id']);
    }
])
->where([
    'Categories.name IN' => $themeNames,
->all();
```

The error is:

```
Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'base.ArticlesCategories.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in [/var/www/mySite/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/MysqlStatement.php, line 36]
```

So as the problems seems to come from the join table, I don't see how to write the `group()` clause.

Comment: this might help you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by

Comment: @ManoharKhadka that's a possibility but I would prefer to fix the problem in the query.

Comment: I think that's not the problem with query..And may be it's not even issue with cakephp..Your query looks all good.

Comment: @ManoharKhadka I don't know, I have this problem for all belongsToMany associations. I begin to think your proposal is maybe the best solution :-(

Comment: which php version are you using ? and does that query work without contain or group by ?

Comment: @ManoharKhadka I'm using php7.0.12 and mysql 5.7.16. All queries work except the ones using `distinct`, `order`, `count`, etc..

Comment: If your relations are all good then this might surely be the problem with mysql version..please just try this in other versions to be sure on that.

Comment: @ManoharKhadka older versions work fine but this problem is well known with 5.7