# Mysql restores ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY after restart

Tags: mysql

I followed the 2nd answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by%20Disable%20ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY) to disable the global option 
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

```
mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)


mysql> SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)


mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                                                             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

I just discovered that after a mysql service restart, this option is restored.

This is my environment

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
MySQL 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 
Ubuntu 16.04
```

I thinked it was in one of the config files, but I'm not able to find it. Can you point me **where is it located** or how to **permanently disable** it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found:

I must add a new line into `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Ensure you have a section name `[mysqld]`

Add after this section  name the following

```
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

> Please, please, please NOTE THIS: This `sql_mode` is specific for my specific situation and use case; when applying this answer to your case, ensure you understand the principle and not copy/paste litterally.
>
> First: read actual sql_mode using `mysql -u root -p -e "SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;"`
>
> Second: apply changes to sql_mode, and test it
>
> Third: using `mysqld.conf` or, better, a custom .cnf file is possible, apply the modification to sql_mode as illustrated above

Then restarted

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

My settings now is preserved after restart.

Comment: I'm getting this error:

Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed Make sure you've added a `[mysqld]` section.

Comment: @MarcGuay It doesn't work to me. I get the sane error of Alaudin Ahmed

Comment: @LuizAlves Perhaps you should ask your own question and include a copy of your mysqld.cnf file.

Comment: I am also gettin the same error of @AlauddinAhmed

Answer (score 4):

You can find (or create) config file in the paths listed here - [Using Option Files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html)

In config file in [mysqld] section write options you need, for example:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
```