# Mysql select only unique rows (that appears only one time)

Tags: php, mysql

Consider following data in table ->

```
1   example@hotmail.com
2   example12@hotmail.com
3   example@hotmail.com
4   example@hotmail.com
```

I want it to return only the following:

```
2   example12@hotmail.com
```

...and skip the duplicate values.

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: have you tried WHERE email = 'example12@hotmail.com' ?

Comment: @barudo  I don't want to use WHERE email = 'example12@hotmail.com'.

Comment: @barudo  needs to select multiple unique rows that does appears only one time, like First time Callers

Comment: so add it in your question. Something like: I need to pick up only records that exists only once... add also what fields in your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you want is

```
SELECT id, email, whatEverColumn 
FROM table 
WHERE email IN (SELECT email 
               FROM table 
               GROUP BY email 
               HAVING COUNT(id) = 1)
```

Comment: Hey, I'm not using primary id, I get this error -> #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'table_name.date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: This error message sounds like one from SQL-Server, not from MySQL. But I'll update my post.

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong. You may want to [set the `sql_mode`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23921117/7605692)

Comment: @Kyoya In MySQL 5.7 that's the new default. Best to get used to it than to fight it and change server settings.

Comment: @tadman I have never used `GROUP BY` on MySQL 5.7. I see I have to expand my knowledge about MySQL.

Comment: This error happens only with phpmyadmin, I could use the syntax directly on php. I think phpmyadmin sets sql_mode by itself. Thanks @Kyoya for your time.

Comment: Now it should have the correct syntax without disabling the SQL mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Answer (score 2):

Group by email and add having count(email) = 1