# #1055 - Expression #6 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1055

I have a problem with the query below in MySQL 5.7, but in MySQL 5.6 it is working well.

This message appears every time:

> 1055 - Expression #6 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
>   'electricity_databases.electricity_invoices.date_inserted' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

SQL code:

```
SELECT 
homes.id,
homes.homeName,
homes.city, 
homes.date_registered,
ROUND(SUM(electricity_invoices.total), 2) AS TotalPrice,
DATEDIFF(NOW(), electricity_invoices.date_inserted) AS last_insert_in_days,
MAX(electricity_invoices.date_inserted) AS last_insert,
COUNT(electricity_invoices.homeID) AS countPaymentTimes,
MAX(electricity_invoices.currRead) AS currRead,
MAX(electricity_invoices.prevRead) AS prevRead,
ROUND(MAX(electricity_invoices.currRead) - MAX(electricity_invoices.prevRead), 1) AS lastComp,
customer.name

FROM homes

LEFT JOIN electricity_invoices ON
homes.id = electricity_invoices.homeID

LEFT JOIN customer ON
homes.id = customer.homeID

GROUP BY homes.id
ORDER BY homes.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that in latest versions of MySQL, be default it is not allowed to not add non aggregated column in the group by clause. You can disable this behavior by disable sql_mode from full group by mode.

Just add the non-aggregated columns in the `group by` clause.

```
select homes.id,
    homes.homeName,
    homes.city,
    homes.date_registered,
    ROUND(SUM(electricity_invoices.total), 2) as TotalPrice,
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), electricity_invoices.date_inserted) as last_insert_in_days,
    MAX(electricity_invoices.date_inserted) as last_insert,
    COUNT(electricity_invoices.homeID) as countPaymentTimes,
    MAX(electricity_invoices.currRead) as currRead,
    MAX(electricity_invoices.prevRead) as prevRead,
    ROUND(MAX(electricity_invoices.currRead) - MAX(electricity_invoices.prevRead), 1) as lastComp,
    customer.name
from homes
left join electricity_invoices on homes.id = electricity_invoices.homeID
left join customer on homes.id = customer.homeID
group by homes.id,
    homes.homeName,
    homes.city,
    homes.date_registered,
    customer.name
```

Comment: how can i do could you explain me please

Comment: @mohdadawe - Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by

Answer (score 0):

starting to mysql 5.7 you can select non aggregated  columns not present in group 
if you want the same behavior of previous versions  you must revoke sql_mode=only_full_group_by  (using SET sql_mode = '')
or more properly you should buil a the select  or assing to group by all the column not aggregated 
eg:

```
SELECT 
homes.id,
homes.homeName,
homes.city, 
homes.date_registered,
ROUND(SUM(electricity_invoices.total), 2) AS TotalPrice,
DATEDIFF(NOW(), electricity_invoices.date_inserted) AS last_insert_in_days,
MAX(electricity_invoices.date_inserted) AS last_insert,
COUNT(electricity_invoices.homeID) AS countPaymentTimes,
MAX(electricity_invoices.currRead) AS currRead,
MAX(electricity_invoices.prevRead) AS prevRead,
ROUND(MAX(electricity_invoices.currRead) - MAX(electricity_invoices.prevRead), 1) AS lastComp,
customer.name

FROM homes

LEFT JOIN electricity_invoices ON
homes.id = electricity_invoices.homeID

LEFT JOIN customer ON
homes.id = customer.homeID

GROUP BY homes.id, homes.homeName,homes.city, homes.date_registered, DATEDIFF(NOW(), electricity_invoices.date_inserted) AS last_insert_in_days
ORDER BY homes.id
```

or , due the fact that you don't need  specific value for these columns , use  (fake) aggregation  for these column

```
SELECT 
homes.id,
min(homes.homeName),
min(homes.city), 
min(homes.date_registered),
ROUND(SUM(electricity_invoices.total), 2) AS TotalPrice,
min(DATEDIFF(NOW(), electricity_invoices.date_inserted) AS last_insert_in_days),
MAX(electricity_invoices.date_inserted) AS last_insert,
COUNT(electricity_invoices.homeID) AS countPaymentTimes,
MAX(electricity_invoices.currRead) AS currRead,
MAX(electricity_invoices.prevRead) AS prevRead,
ROUND(MAX(electricity_invoices.currRead) - MAX(electricity_invoices.prevRead), 1) AS lastComp,
customer.name

FROM homes

LEFT JOIN electricity_invoices ON
homes.id = electricity_invoices.homeID

LEFT JOIN customer ON
homes.id = customer.homeID

GROUP BY homes.id
ORDER BY homes.id
```

Comment: how to disable sql_mode, and if i disabled it can damage the database

Comment: No .. you don't damage the database ... only you use the same (old and unpredicatble )mode  used by previous version.. But using the old mode you use group by in the wrong way ..