# this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My SQL query is not working showing this error:

> this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I am running this query in other mysql pannel there have working fine. In new server is not working....

If i run this then error is not working and also `group by` is not working

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

New server version

Client API library version  : mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $
PHP Version 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4

Comment: Correct. The default setting has been changed. Invalid GROUP BY clauses do now by default raise an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `SET sql_mode = '';` before your query;

My guess is that your mysql version is 5.7 where it's not working, which has changed the setting.

Comment: Yes! Would you please guide me how to resolve this issues.

Comment: as I said - just run the query i enclosed before once.

Answer (score 2):

Can't be sure without seeing your query, but I assume you're using different sets of columns in your `select` and in your `group by` clauses.

```
select  a, b, sum(c)
from    table
group by a
```

If that's the case, you can write your query like on of these, depending on what you actually want

```
select  a, b, sum(c)
from    table
group by a, b
```

or

```
select  a, sum(c)
from    table
group by a
```

Note that this is how `group by` has to be used in almost any database. MySQL allowing for different sets is the anomaly.

Answer (score 1):

See [Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by) for more answers. The answers here didn't work for me, but editing my.cnf, as suggested there worked. I tested mysql-server 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 from Ubuntu 16.04.

But of course the proper solution is to fix your query... reverting the old bad behavior is just a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to replace `global` statement by `session`:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this very clear explanation.

There seems to be an exception to this rule that all columns in a Select clause with a Group By must be in the Group By clause. This is where the Group By column is the key field.

You might wonder why this would ever be interesting, since by definition a key from one table will only every produce one unique record.

This could be useful in case of a join, where you want to count the number of joined records in the joined table but also show the detail from the first table, eg:

- Table 1 - names: key Id, field fullname
- Table 2 - purchases: key Id, field name, field purchase, linked to Table 1 by purchases.name=names.id

```
select * from names;
```

| Id | Fullname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Foobar |
| 2 | Jane Woobar |

```
select * from purchases;
```

| Id | Name | Purchase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | car |
| 2 | 1 | book |
| 3 | 1 | holiday |
| 4 | 2 | hat |

```
Select names.Id, fullname, count(purchase) from (purchases left join names on purchases.name = names.Id) group by (names.Id);
```

| Id | fullname | count(purchase) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Foobar | 3 |
| 2 | Jane Woobar | 1 |