# Codeigniter Query Builder Object Error After Upgrade

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query-builder

Long time lurker, first time asker.

Quick version:
I'm getting 500 errors on a LAMP site following an apt-get upgrade, which I can best trace back to Codeigniter's Query Builder.

Long version:

Codebase: Codeigniter 3.1.5 (upgraded as part of troubleshooting)

> Local environment (works fine): XAMPP 7.0.3 / PHP 7.0.21 / MariaDB
>   10.1.25
>
> Production environment (returns error): PHP 7.0.21 /  MySQL Ver 14.14
>   Distrib 5.7.19

Depending on the page, I get a 500 HTTP error.  Logs show various versions of this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /var/www/application/models/Model.php on line xxx
```

Each of these errors refers to a piece of Codeigniter Query Builder code similar to:

```
$query = $this->db->query([some query]);
return $query->result();
```

or

```
$this->db->group_by([some other field]);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

I can't find any consistent patterns across my use of query builder, though `$this->db->group_by()` seems to be popular.

Each error suggests that there's a problem with the `query` object but - again - it's inconsistent and confusing.

Steps to resolve:

- Attempted to get version parity across environments
- Rolled back the apt-get upgrade
- Re-did apt-get upgrade
- Upgraded Codeigniter from 3.1.3 to 3.1.5
- Did a bunch of googling

I'm stumped.  Any help or insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did more digging and was able to get a further error message in MySQL.  This lead me here: [Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by).

Followed the steps and was able to resolve the problem.