# made sql_mode blank from my.cnf in centos 7 still got this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, sql-mode

Stuck in an issue with sql_mode restriction. Made the change in /etc/my.cnf and restart the mysql.d but getting the same error.

**In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'gamenew.user_profiles.account_id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by**

phpmyadmin have a blank in sql mode

my mysql version is 5.7
and CENTOS version is 7

the code is working fine in latest version on mysql in my local system.
I have made lots of SP so can't prefer this link
[Stored procedure raising "incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by" despite sql_mode being blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45560680/stored-procedure-raising-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by-despite)

Comment: Either you have not restarted the mysql server or you edited the wrong config file. However, it would be a lot better if you did not disable this sql mode and wrote queries that actually complied with the sql standards. With this sql mode disabled your query may run, but the results are amy not be what you expected.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I checked it by changing sql_mode from PHPMyAdmin for  temporary basis the query is working fine as normal SQL query but not in stored procedure in MySQL 5.7

Comment: already seen that post. but for some other solution i had posted this question..

Comment: Why do you need another solution?

Comment: pre built product can't change whole functionality

Comment: You don't have to change, just recreate it.

Comment: issue has been resolved thanx for the help..