# MySQL query is not working on Linux

Tags: mysql, linux

I have a MySQL query for sales by month report, but when I try to execute it on my Linux box Debian it didn't work anymore. It works on my Windows box, and my query looks like this. I have to order my sales by month, but however doesn't it.

How can I fix it?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS orders, ROUND(SUM(total),2) AS total, MONTHNAME(created_at) AS MONTH
    FROM storelte_order
    WHERE STATUS = 1
    AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE())
    GROUP BY MONTH 
    ORDER BY created_at ASC;
```

Error:

```
22:14:34 call sales_by_month Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'storelte.storelte_order.created_at' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by 0.041 sec
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you can fix it in two ways

1. Reconfigure your linux mysql as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by)
2. Rewrite your query (let say replace created_at by 3 (means MONTH column in result).

Comment: I just rewrite query instead of created_at to 3

Comment: Try to use column name, not index.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) AS orders, ROUND(SUM(total),2) AS total, MONTHNAME(created_at) AS MONTH
 FROM storelte_order
 WHERE STATUS = 1
 AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE())
 GROUP BY MONTH 
 ORDER BY created_at ASC;

this is what my query look like now.

Comment: in fact you wrote same query. You need something like