# How to fetch single image from an array of inserted Images in laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, image, laravel-5.4

**Controller function:**

```
<?php

public function addImages(Request $request, $imagesProductId) {

    $product = Product::create($request->all());
    $filenames = array();

    if (empty($request->images)) {
        $message = "error";
        return Redirect::back()->with('message', $message);
    }


    $rules = [
        'images' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'                 // allowed MIMEs
// size in pixels
    ];



    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    $result = $validator->fails() ? 'QCVerified' : 'QCFailed';



    foreach ($request->images as $photo) {

//  echo($result);
        $filename = $photo->store('public/uploadedImages');
        $filename = substr($filename, 22);
        $filenames[] = asset('storage/uploadedImages/' . $filename);
        ProductsPhoto::create([
            'nonliveStatus' => $result,
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'productId' => $imagesProductId,
            'filename' => $filename
        ]);
    }
    return response()->json($filenames);
}
?>
```

This is my storage function for storing array of images.

**Function To fetch single image from an array of images:**

```
<?php
$liveValues = priceInfo::join('productDescription', 'productDescription.productId', '=', 'productPriceDetails.productId')
        ->join('productAdditionalInformation', 'productAdditionalInformation.productId', '=', 'productPriceDetails.productId')
        ->join('products_photos', 'products_photos.productId', '=', 'productAdditionalInformation.productId')
        ->select('products_phots.filename')
        ->where('productPriceDetails.nonliveStatus', '=', "QCVerified")
        ->get();
?>
```

Here I am selecting the imagefile from the table.It fetches the multiple images stored based on single id.But I need only one images from the array of images stored.

Comment: use limit in your query to get the single image

Comment: will you please specifiy it clearly

Comment: I suggest to use `->groupBy('productPriceDetails.productId')` as a solution. but the main problem is in your database design

Answer (score 3):

Your current database query simply lists all possible filenames because there's no ID restriction added.

Since the OP states that you want to look up a file name based on a single ID and your comments on other answers indicate you don't want to limit the fetched records, you could extend your query to include an ID and then perform a search in the resulting Collection:

```
// I've included the "productId" column here, but feel free to include any other column as required.
$liveValues = priceInfo::join('productDescription',     'productDescription.productId', '=', 'productPriceDetails.productId')
                       ->join('productAdditionalInformation',     'productAdditionalInformation.productId', '=', 'productPriceDetails.productId')
                       ->join('products_photos', 'products_photos.productId', '=',     'productAdditionalInformation.productId')
                       ->select('products_photos.productId', 'products_photos.filename')
                       ->where('productPriceDetails.nonliveStatus', '=', "QCVerified")
                       ->get();

// Get the image filename for a given productId.
// ID calculation logic here.
$productId = 512; // Sample ID

// $liveValues is a Collection.
$filename = $liveValues->where('productId', $productId)
                        ->pluck('filename')
                        ->first(); // Get first filename if there are multiple.
```

Of course this is just an example of how to tackle this. You'll definitely need to adjust this to fit in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code the limited records

```
<?php
$liveValues = priceInfo::join('productDescription', 'productDescription.productId', '=', 'productPriceDetails.productId')
        ->join('productAdditionalInformation', 'productAdditionalInformation.productId', '=', 'productPriceDetails.productId')
        ->join('products_photos', 'products_photos.productId', '=', 'productAdditionalInformation.productId')
        ->select('products_phots.filename')
        ->where('productPriceDetails.nonliveStatus', '=', "QCVerified")
        ->limit(1)
        ->get();
    ?>
```

**check the below updated code**:
Here you will group the images by products and will get the single product image

```
<?php
$liveValues = priceInfo::join('productDescription', 'productDescription.productId', '=', 'productPriceDetails.productId')
    ->join('productAdditionalInformation', 'productAdditionalInformation.productId', '=', 'productPriceDetails.productId')
    ->join('products_photos', 'products_photos.productId', '=', 'productAdditionalInformation.productId')
    ->select('products_phots.filename')
    ->where('productPriceDetails.nonliveStatus', '=', "QCVerified")
    ->limit(1)
    ->groupBy('products_photos.productId')
    ->get();
?>
```

Comment: Sorry,I don't want to limit the records.I just Only want limit the images I'm fetching

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'GemSeller.products_photos.filename' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: I guess your mysql version is above 5.6, which do support only full group by default, use the following answer to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23921234/6582942

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$liveValues = priceInfo::join('productDescription', 'productDescription.productId', '=', 'productPriceDetails.productId')
        ->join('productAdditionalInformation', 'productAdditionalInformation.productId', '=', 'productPriceDetails.productId')
        ->join('products_photos', 'products_photos.productId', '=', 'productAdditionalInformation.productId')
        ->select('products_phots.filename')
        ->where('productPriceDetails.nonliveStatus', '=', "QCVerified")
        ->get();
?>
```

In this code use first() instead of get().

Comment: Here too,it limits the records i'm fetching

Answer (score 1):

If you understand well, then you have a lot of product photos.
If you have a photo in the database that is a main photo, then you can build a query like:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... 
    [LEFT] JOIN products_photos 
        ON products_photos.productId = productAdditionalInformation.productId 
            AND products_photos.is_main = 1
```

Otherwise use sub-query

```
SELECT ... , (SELECT filename FROM products_photos WHERE productId = productAdditionalInformation.productId [ORDER BY productId  DESC]) 
    FROM ...
```

Sorry for using SQL notation, but I do not know the query-bulder lawrell. And this is just a typical problem with building SQL queries.