# how to find distinct results that are ordered by the number of instances found in a MySQL search?

Tags: mysql

I need to find distinct videos that are not viewed or uploaded by user logged in and are ordered by the number of instances found in a MySQL search

And it finds the needed videos as it should but it finds videos that contain more than 1 of the searched tags the number of tags searched for times and all with the same score

So if it searches for tag1 and tag2 and 1 video contains tag1 - and another video contains tag1 and tag2

The result is:
Video1 - single score
Video2 - single score
Video2 - single score
All 3 with the same score

And what I need is for it to find only distinct videos but which score reflects how many tags of the searched ones it contains

The needed result: (in correct order)
Video2 - double score (contains 2 tags)
Video1 - single score (contains 1 tag)

If you want to test you can click the link below and change
the 2 instances of userID = ... (1,2,3 to choose from)
and
the 2 instances of tags MATCH (vtn.tag) AGAINST ('...' IN BOOLEAN MODE) (politics,news,social,other to chose from)
(just remember to make the 2 instances of userID the same and the 2 instances of tags the same)

[To test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6330c4/1)

To that end I have the following SELECT statement

```
SELECT v.id AS vID , v.date AS vDate , v.seriestitle AS vSeriestitle , v.seriesnumber AS vSeriesnumber , v.title AS vTitle , v.randomString AS vRandomString , u.username AS uUsername , u.randomString AS uRandomString , ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videoview AS vv WHERE vv.videoID = v.id ) AS videoviews , MATCH ( vtn.tag ) AGAINST ( '$tags' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) AS score FROM video AS v LEFT JOIN userlogininfo AS u ON v.userID = u.id LEFT JOIN videotag AS vt ON vt.videoID = v.id LEFT JOIN videotagname AS vtn ON vtn.id = vt.tagID WHERE MATCH ( vtn.tag ) AGAINST ( '$tags' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) AND v.userID != ? AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL FROM videoview AS vvn WHERE vvn.userID = ? AND vvn.videoID = v.id ) ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT ?
```

Or more readable:

```
SELECT 
    v.id AS vID , 
    v.date AS vDate , 
    v.seriestitle AS vSeriestitle , 
    v.seriesnumber AS vSeriesnumber , 
    v.title AS vTitle , 
    v.randomString AS vRandomString , 
    u.username AS uUsername , 
    u.randomString AS uRandomString , 
    ( SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM videoview AS vv 
    WHERE vv.videoID = v.id ) AS videoviews , 
    MATCH ( vtn.tag ) AGAINST ( '$tags' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) AS score 
FROM video AS v 

LEFT JOIN userlogininfo AS u 
ON v.userID = u.id 

LEFT JOIN videotag AS vt 
ON vt.videoID = v.id 

LEFT JOIN videotagname AS vtn 
ON vtn.id = vt.tagID 

WHERE 
    MATCH ( vtn.tag ) AGAINST ( '$tags' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) 
    AND v.userID != ? 
    AND NOT EXISTS 
        ( SELECT NULL FROM videoview AS vvn WHERE vvn.userID = ? 
        AND vvn.videoID = v.id ) 
ORDER BY score DESC 
LIMIT ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to group all the `tag` for a particular `video title/id`.

For this, you need group by `v.title` and `group_concat(vtn.tag)`.

`Group_concat(vtn.tag)` will concat all the tags for a particular video title.

Unfortunately, we can't use `group_concat(vtn.tag)` inside `Match()`.

Now, we **can** join a subquery that will select `videoID` and all relevant tags to that id inside select query. But the problem is, in order to make `MATCH()..AGAINST()` work properly, we need to have `FULLINDEX` on the column of the table.

Hence, the **only** solution I can see here is to create another table that contains `videoID` and all their `tag` in a **single row**.

**SOLUTION:**

```
CREATE TABLE `mergevideotag` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `videoID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag` text NOT NULL,
   FULLTEXT(`tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Insert into mergevideotag(videoID,tag)
select vt1.videoID as id,
        Group_concat(distinct vtn1.tag order by vtn1.tag desc separator ' ') as tag
            from videotag vt1
            LEFT join videotagname vtn1
            on vt1.tagID = vtn1.id
            group by vt1.videoID
;
```

Final **Select** query:

```
  SELECT 
  v.id AS vID , 
  v.date AS vDate , 
  v.seriestitle AS vSeriestitle , 
  v.seriesnumber AS vSeriesnumber , 
  v.title AS vTitle , 
  v.randomString AS vRandomString , 
  u.username AS uUsername , 
  u.randomString AS uRandomString , 
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videoview AS vv WHERE vv.videoID = v.id ) AS videoviews , 
   m.tag as tag, 
  MATCH (m.tag) AGAINST ('other social' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
FROM video AS v 
LEFT JOIN userlogininfo AS u ON v.userID = u.id 
LEFT JOIN videotag AS vt ON vt.videoID = v.id 
LEFT JOIN videotagname AS vtn ON vtn.id = vt.tagID 
LEFT JOIN mergevideotag AS m ON vt.videoID = m.videoID            
WHERE 
  MATCH ( vtn.tag ) AGAINST ( 'other social' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
  AND v.userID != 2 
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL FROM videoview AS vvn WHERE vvn.userID = 2 AND vvn.videoID = v.id ) 
  group by v.id, m.tag
  order by score desc
;
```

[Click here for DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/850db/14/0)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please try the answer as well as check the demo.

Comment: @Hashil It looks like it should work after CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO but the INSERT INTO that follows throws a '#1064 - There is an ERROR in SQL syntax near 'DISTINCT vtn1.tag ORDER BY vtn1.tag DESC seperator ' ') AS tag FROM videotag AS ' on line 1'

Comment: It works fine in the demo and I couldn't find anything wrong about the statement. It looks like a typo or mistake in copy paste maybe. Can you please try it again?

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: Remove the last line from select query : `select *from mergevideotag` is a different query.

Comment: Also remove `;` after `desc`

Comment: did both but var_dump($getVideo); still gives same notice

Comment: Please run select query on database directly (not from php)  and comment here whether it's working properly or not.

Comment: Also, according to my knowledge, query inside prepare() should be written in single quotes. '' not the double quotes "".

Comment: It throws a '#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'v.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by'

Comment: Ok. You need to change the mode. Write the statement given in following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36033983/2225030

Comment: Apparantly it should be 'group by v.id , m.tag' and it works perfectly... edit your answer to match and you'll get your checkmark for answered :) and a million times thank you... much appreciated your hard work on this :)

Comment: Is it really worked by adding only those 2 columns in group by? Or did u remove some columns from select too?

Comment: yes... only change was removing the v.title and add  'v.id , m.tag' to the group by and it found the right videos with the right score and ordered them perfectly - I changed nothing else

Comment: Thank you. You can remove the update from your question as it may confuse the future visitors.

Comment: it is now removed :)

Answer (score 0):

select distinct, that would only give distinct result, every other things seems alright in your query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```

Comment: yes it gets only distinct videos but it still sets the score as the same which means I still can't order them correctly... so how do I change the score to reflect how many of the searched tags every video contains?

Comment: you have to concatenate the tags for every video, and then have to math for that concatenated tags string to get correct score