# Exclude records from Query Builder Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

My table have these data:

```
ID  | company_id   | code   | description
01  |  NULL        | CD01   | Standard description CD01
02  |  NULL        | XYZU   | Standard description XYZU
03  |  1           | CD01   | Custom description CD01 for company 1
04  |  2           | CD01   | Custom description CD01 for company 2
```

I need to extract all 'code' from this table but showing a single product code only once.

If exists a record witht company_id <> '' I show that, instead if doesn't exists I show the record with standard description.

Starting from the sample data, if I wanted to show the articles for the company_id = 1, I expect to have this output:

```
ID   | company_id   | code   | description   
02   |  NULL        | XYZU   | Standard description XYZU
03   |  1           | CD01   | Custom description CD01 for company 1
```

Have you got some suggest to do it?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried Records::whereNull('company_id')->orWhere('company_id',$companyId)->groupBy('code')->get();

Comment: I've tried just now but ths system returns an SQL error: "1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP by clause and contains nonaggregated column which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 2):

for removing duplicate entries from database results by group by you should disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY for mysql. don't do that in mysql and don't disable strict mode! laravel itself sets some modes.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by) is the overall solution for disabling this mode.

but in laravel you should also try another thing:

go to `YouProjectFolder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php`

at the end of the file fin `strict_mode()` function and just remove `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` fr0m the string within the function.
(i just saw this solution in a stackoverflow post. unfortunately i didn't find that post)

Comment: I've disabledONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in: YouProjectFolder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php

Comment: now check this mode existence in your sql. if it disabled there too you can use group by for selecting distinct results.