# Laravel 5.5 - Get users and group by month

Tags: laravel

I am trying to return all users from my Laravel 5.5 database and group them by the month they registered like this..

```
$users = DB::table('users')
     ->orderBy('created_at')
     ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"))
     ->get();
```

But this is giving me an error

```
Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
```

Where am I going wrong?

** Update **

The exact error mesage I am getting is...

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'myapp.users.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `name`, `email`, MONTH(created_at) month from `users` group by `month` order by `created_at` asc)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by

Answer (score 0):

You can try as:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->select('name','email',DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) month'))
->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
->groupby('month')
->get();
```

Comment: That is giving me the same error message, I have updated the original post with the full message