# Why Raw sql doesnt work in laravel DB

Tags: sql, laravel, rawsql

I have this sentence:

```
$lastOperationUser = DB::select("SELECT last_operation FROM policies
                        INNER JOIN(users) 
                        ON (policies.user_id=users.id)
                        group by (user_id);");
```

If I execute in my phpmyadmin works fine but in laravel throw this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'test.policies.last_operation' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT last_operation FROM policies INNER JOIN(users) ON (policies.user_id=users.id) group by (user_id);)
```

My model is:

```
USERS         POLICIES
id            id
name          last_operation
              user_id
```

One to many relationship

Any help please?

Comment: None of your tables have a field named `user_id`.

Comment: Sorry. Mistake in model. Now is correct. But error still

Comment: May be some library?

Comment: READ `'test.policies.last_operation' isn't in GROUP BY`

Comment: `group by (user_id, last_operation)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable ONLY\_FULL\_GROUP\_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by)

Comment: There can be multiple `last_operation` values per `user_id`. Which one do you want to get?

Comment: Is a date I want the newest

Comment: have you tried your query in database tool like mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the description of what you're looking for from various comments, the following should be close to what you're after:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(last_operation) AS last_operation
  FROM policies
  JOIN users
    ON policies.user_id = users.id
  GROUP BY user_id
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thats worked.  In the view I did an foreach:   ´@foreach($lastOperationUser as $last_operation)
                                                    @if( $last_operation->user_id == $user->id)
                                                          {{  $last_operation->last_operation }}
                                                    @endif
                                                @endforeach´

Answer (score 0):

The first is you have to make sure that your sql query can return something in your database tool like mysql or sqlite or etc.. After that change your code into like this:

```
$lastOperationUser = DB::table('policies')->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'policies.user_id')
                                          ->select('last_operation')
                                          ->groupBy('user_id')
                                          ->get();
```

I think that you can use like this without use DB raw

if occurs error, go to `config\database.php` and set `'strict' => false`

Comment: This sentence throw error: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 last_operation' isn't in GROUP BY

Comment: If I insert last_operation in GROUP BY, now throw error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id, last_operation' in 'group statement'

Comment: go to your `config\database.php` and change `'strict' => false`