# Get cheapest price for a product

Tags: mysql, join, select, distinct

I have two tables: `products` and `prices`

`products`

- id (PK)
- name

`prices`

- id (PK)
- product_id (FK > products)
- price
- originalPrice

Each product might have multiple prices. What I want to achieve is a query that returns me `all products on-sale with its cheapest price`.

- `on-sale` = price < originalPrice
- if a product is **not** `on-sale`, it should not be included in the results
- if a product has multiple prices that qualify for `on-sale`, only return the cheapest price.

**The resulting table should have these columns**

- products.id
- products.name
- prices.id
- prices.price
- prices.originalPrice

With my attempts I'm ending up with this issue: `#1055 - Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'tbl.price' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`. **Please note that I cannot change the config.**

**MySQL version:** 5.7.22

**I have uploaded a SQL export with sample data here:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ucdv6592dum6n6/stackoverflow_export.sql?dl=0

Comment: Can you provide the TABLE schema with data?

Comment: Which column mark `on-sale` or  not `on-sale`

Comment: I have uploaded a SQL export with sample data here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ucdv6592dum6n6/stackoverflow_export.sql?dl=0

Comment: Added answer below can you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `products` pro
JOIN price pri on pri.productId = pro.id
WHERE pri.price < pri.originalPrice
AND pri.price = 
( 
    SELECT min(p.price) 
    FROM price p 
    WHERE p.productId = pro.id AND p.price < p.originalPrice 
)
```

Comment: cool, this one works perfectly - even though I just updated the requirements in my question. Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
select pro.name, MIN(pri.price) from products pro
inner join price pri on pri.product_id = pro.id 
where pri.price < pri.originalPrice 
group by pro.name
```

heres a shot without any data :p may need a little tweaking

Comment: Your aggregation function will return the topmost grouped row not the cheapest

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you

```
SELECT *,MIN(price)  FROM (
SELECT name, products.id,price
FROM products
INNER JOIN productItems
   ON products.id = productItems.productId
WHERE price < originalPrice
ORDER BY (price-originalPrice)
) as tbl GROUP BY id;
```

OR

```
SELECT *,MIN(diff)  FROM (
SELECT name, products.id,price,(price-originalPrice) as "diff"
FROM products
INNER JOIN productItems
   ON products.id = productItems.productId
WHERE price < originalPrice
ORDER BY products.id,(price-originalPrice)
) as tbl GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: I had tried something like that before. Unfortunately I end up with: `#1055 - Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'tbl.price' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`
_(using mysql 5.7.22, I cannot change the config)_

Comment: It means you cannot use other fields when you are using `GROUP BY` with `aggregation` function. In this case either you need to handle the values at application end.

Comment: Have some tricks but not working with the latest MySql https://stackoverflow.com/a/36033983/8179245

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question.. unfortunately I cannot update the config.

Answer (score 1):

This works with that dropbox link you gave: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6306d/3

```
 select pro.name, MIN(pri.price) from products pro
    inner join price pri on pri.productId = pro.id 
    where pri.price < pri.originalPrice 
    group by pro.name
```

Comment: Hope it helps! Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question.. unfortunately I need more information in the resulting table (such as `price.id`). Cool tool (sqlfiddle)!