# Select two columns from two tables doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get login and count that are in different tables but it doesn't work

Here is what I'm doing:

```
SELECT login AS "Login", COUNT(posted) AS "Nombre" FROM members, wallmsg;
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'sc_social.members.login'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: May be you want to do

Comment: You should `group by login`... I think, and also provide the join between the 2 tables.

Comment: share data set of two tables and expected result and your try that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

To fetch data from two tables in SQL, you first need to add join between the tables.
Whenever you uses any aggregate functions like "Count", you have to use "GroupBy" clause.
    SELECT m.login,COUNT(w.posted) FROM members m inner join wallmsg w on     m.SomeId =w.SomeId
group by m.login

Answer (score 0):

You have set sql mode on **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY**, you should change it by:

`SET sql_mode = ''`

and see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by) for detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
SELECT
  Orders.OrderID,
  Customers.CustomerName,
  Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
  INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID;
```