# Symfony query with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY ON

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, group-by

I want to retrive a collection of object as result of cities grouped by name, my query is

```
public function getDistinctCitiesName()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("cc");
            ->add('groupBy', 'cc.name');

    return $qb;
}
```

When run i have an exception

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An exception occurred while
>   executing 'SELECT c0_.id AS id_0, c0_.name AS name_1, c0_.postal_code
>   AS postal_code_2, c0_.country AS country_3, c0_.state AS state_4,
>   c0_.visible AS visible_5 FROM cities c0_ GROUP BY c0_.name': 
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1
>   of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column 'www.c0_.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in
>   GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

I can't disable the only_full_group_by mode, so is there a solution ?

Comment: Your query doesn't contain any aggregated columns, it is not allowed into [only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode. Consider rewriting your query to include aggregates

Comment: thanks, but rewriting query does not return a collection on object

Comment: Query with an aggregation doesn't mean to return complete rows of the table at all, it is about SQL, not Doctrine. Try to think about your goal, what do you actually want to achieve by this `groupBy` clause?

Comment: I need a collection to use it in form field 'query_builder'

Comment: Your method name is `getDistinctCitiesName` so I can assume that your actual query should look like `select distinct(name) from cities`, but your actual query is different.

Comment: Thanks, but as said i want retrive a collection of object, select distinct return only array of values

Comment: In this case you need to either retrieve collection of objects and extract distinct names from them manually or write query that will load distinct names (but not objects!) from database

Comment: Thanks @Flying,
so I do not really have the choice, it's an annoying limitation.

Comment: Actually it is not a limitation, but a way that relational databases are working. I would recommend you to update your query to use `select distinct` and fetch single column of values to avoid loading unnecessary data in application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by

Comment: @hous full-group-by is the correct way to create a SQL query, disable it does not exist in other DBMS except mysql as i know...

Answer (score 7):

You need to disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from mySQL to get rid of this exception.
There are two options for you:-

1:- Disable it in the doctrine configuration

```
options:
    1002: 'SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY", ""))'
```

If you add this to the doctrine configuration, you won't get the exception anymore.

2:- Disable it in the mySQL
Either Run the following command inside mysql console

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Or delete it from phpmyadmin
[disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcKHv.png)

This is my [blog](https://webkul.com/blog/disable-only_full_group_by-in-doctrine/) on this topic. You could check it and share your review.

Thanks!

Comment: Adding the 1002 option in doctrine configuration works fine ! Thanks. My questions are "Why this option ?  Will this modification cause some other issue ?"