# laravel query building with a lot of joins

Tags: mysql, laravel

my sql query is

```
$q = "SELECT 
                file,
                roleId,
                page,
                type,
                userType,
                COUNT(DISTINCT($a)) as 'a',
                COUNT(DISTINCT($b)) as 'b'
            FROM table_name
            WHERE
                course IN ($type)
                AND date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'
                AND (course_1 is NULL OR course_1 NOT IN ('ABCD'))
                AND deleted IS NULL
                AND type LIKE '%Professor%'
                AND action = 'submit'
                GROUP BY file, roleId";
```

I want to convert that query into laravel query builder like

```
$orders = DB::table('table_name')
                ->select('file', 'roleId', 'page', 'type', userType DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT(($a)) as 'a'))
                ->groupBy('file', 'roleId')
                ->get();
```

Do understand how to add the other COUNT into it and how and where to chain the ->where() ?

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` is wrong, it's mandatory grouping result set by all columns that exists at your `SELECT` statment but those product of an aggregation function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

$orders = DB::table('table_name')
->whereIn('course', $courseTypes)
->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate])
->where(function($q){
    return $q->whereNull('course_1')
    ->orWhereNotIn('course_1', $courseArrayToFilter);
})
->whereNull('deleted')
->where('type', 'like', '%Professor%')
->where('action', 'submit')
->groupBy('file', 'roleId')
->select(
    'file',
    'roleId',
    'page',
    'type',
    'userType',
    \DB::raw("COUNT(DISTINCT($a)) as a"),
    \DB::raw("COUNT(DISTINCT($b) as b")
)
->get();
```

Comment: Error . Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Building::cleanBuildings() must be an array, string given

Comment: Wherever  you have whereIn or WhereNotIt etc, you need to pass a php array and not comma separated string.

Comment: Still Error ... access violation:1055 select list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column file which is not functionally dependent on group by clause

Comment: For that you need to work on your basic query. What essentially it means, in MySQL if you are using group by, then you can not directly select non-aggregated columns. To disable this only_full_group_by setting and that error should go away

Comment: how to disable??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in a cleanest way doing this:

- Use the Model instance in inspite of invoke the `DB` facade
- Use `whereRaw` to pass complex or pure SQL queries
- Use `selectRaw()` to process pure SQL queries for instance functions like `COUNT`
- Use Multiple `WHERE` to emulate `AND` operator
- Use `whereIn` to filter ranges of data
- You need to `GROUP BY` all columns in your `SELECT` **you have an error at this point, I mean your query is wrong**

Code

```
$data = Model::select('file', 'roleId', 'page', 'type', 'userType')
                ->selectRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT($a)) as a')
                ->selectRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT($b)) as b')
                ->whereRaw('type IN $type')
                ->whereIn('date', [$startDate, $endDate])
                ->whereRaw("course_1 IS NULL OR course_1 NOT IN('ABCD')")
                ->whereNull('deleted')
                ->where('type', 'LIKE', "%".'Professor'."%")
                ->where('action', '=', 'submit')
                ->groupBy('file', 'roleId', 'page', 'type', 'userType')
                ->get();
```