# How To Use MySQL Group Concat

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, group-concat

I have following Table

```
| id | a | b | c |
-------------------
| 1  | x | y | r |
| 2  | x | y | q |
| 3  | x | y | f |
```

Result should be

```
| a | b | c |
-------------
| x | y | r,q,f |
```

Tried with

```
select a, b, group_concat(c) from table;
```

but it says:

> Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'table.table'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by

Comment: The error said it all "Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query **without GROUP BY**" The error is right you can't mix non aggregate columns with a aggregate (GROUP_CONCAT) colum it is not ANSI SQL..  But notice the error saids **without GROUP BY**, try adding `GROUP BY a, b` pretty sure that would give you the correct results.

Comment: @AbdullahAlShakib No disabling that sql_mode is a bad idea..

Comment: i think, here is rather an issue with the query, than a duplicate ... the query would look better, if: `select a, b, group_concat(c) from table GROUP BY a, b;`

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` is an aggregate function, which means that it requires you to group your results.

This query returns your expected results :

```
SELECT a, b, GROUP_CONCAT(c ORDER BY id) c
FROM mytable
GROUP BY a, b
```

Notes :

- `,` is the default separator for `GROUP_CONCAT`
- `GROUP_CONCAT` supports `ORDER BY`

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a97d9484baaf8d6dab45d7f02cd3237)** :

```
a  | b  | c
:- | :- | :----
x  | y  | r,q,f
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c SEPARATOR ',') from table
Group By a,b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

SELECT a, b, GROUP_CONCAT(c) c
FROM table
GROUP BY a,b