# Disabling only_full_group_by in mysql using sql_mode

Tags: mysql, sql-mode

I have migrated my database from older version to newer one.

I have mysql version 5.7.24 now.

I am getting `ERROR 1055 (sql_mode=only_full_group_by)` for a query which has group by.

I have set sql_mode='' in both global variable as well as my.cnf file and restarted mysql server.

Still problem persists and getting the same error.

Please help me out resolving this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable ONLY\_FULL\_GROUP\_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by)

Comment: Consider to fix your queries instead of disabling `only_full_group_by`.