# Google Cloud Sql Second Generation, error “sql mode error”

Tags: mysql

I changed the `sql_mode` to `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`,

however, the instance says the following error:

```
`SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column '.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`
```

Comment: It appears `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` flag is not supported by the Cloud SQL product. This would explain the issues are you encountering. You may find further information regarding the `sql_mode` flag [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#mysql-s)

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/36033983/10910692