# MySQL : How TO Use ANY_VALUE with all the column of DB table

Tags: mysql

Facing the issue of

> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by;

to resolve the issue, now use `ANY_VALUE(<column_name>)`, It resolves the issue.

But, in some mysql query, We have to use all the columns of db table; where I have used * like :

```
SELECT * FROM db_table GROUP BY Col_1;
```

Now How can I apply `ANY_VALUE`, to the above query.

Please guide.

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(*) FROM db_table GROUP BY Col_1;
```

Throws error.

Comment: `any_value(<column>)` for all columns `<column>`, like `any_value(column1), any_value(column2), ..., any_value(columnn)`?

Comment: `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));` more details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by)

Comment: @danish-khan-I I did the same; but after server restart,  ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled again.

Answer (score 5):

If you just a need  value  you must apply the any_value() function to each column you want select  eg:

```
    SELECT Col_1, any_value(col_2), any_value(col3) 
    FROM db_table 
    GROUP BY Col_1;
```

Comment: Is there any method where one by one column is not mentioned?
Something like SELECT ANY_VALUE(*). Please confirm.

Comment: I confirm .. you can't use any_value(*)   .. you must explicitally use each column name  you want select  ..

Answer (score 0):

Try using [any_value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value):

```
 SELECT any_value(t.col) 
    FROM table as t
    GROUP BY t.Col_1;
```