# Retrieve data from mySQL table in a array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a data table named `CallTriggers` with the attributs

```
cloturer = 0 or 1
created_at
```

and I want to get all the data like this

```
$array = [
           ['Month', 'Total Call', 'Close'],
           ['Jan', 57, 50],
           ['Feb', 67, 60],
           ['Mar', 40, 40],
           ['Apr', 33, 30],
           ['May', 70, 66]
       ];
```

`Example:` ['Jan', 57, 50] here jan is the month, 57 is number of call in the month with value 1 and 50 is number of that the value is 0 in database.

How can I perform that kind of operation with `Laravel 5.6`? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Model**

```php
class CallTrigger extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'CallTriggers';
}
```

**Controller function**

```php
$triggers = CallTrigger::all()
    ->groupBy(function($callTrigger) {
        return $callTrigger->created_at->format('M') .'-' . $callTrigger->created_at->format('Y');
    })
    ->map(function($group, $groupName) {
        return [
            $groupName,
            $group->where('cloturer', 1)->count(),
            $group->where('cloturer', 0)->count(),
        ];
    })
    ->values();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to [execute a raw query](https://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries):

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%b') AS `Month`, 
  SUM(IF(`cloturer` = 1, 1, 0)) AS `Total Call`, 
  SUM(IF(`cloturer` = 0, 1, 0)) AS `Close` 
FROM 
  `CallTriggers` 
GROUP BY 
  MONTH(`created_at`), YEAR(`created_at`);
```

You need to [disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by) in MySQL for this.

Comment: If an answer suggests to disable only full group by sql mode, then that answer cannot be correct.

Comment: thank you guy, it's working fine now