# How to configure MySQL instance with multiline command flag in docker-compose.yml

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I want to launch MySQL local instance with docker image usage.

So far my `docker-compose.yml` file looks like:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:8
     command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
     volumes:
       - ./mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
       MYSQL_DATABASE: sqlPractice
       MYSQL_USER: admin
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
     ports:
      - '7142:3306'
     security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
```

Till this moment everything works. My database is supplied with data but after one query execution like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT surname, name, data FROM exams e JOIN students s ON e.`id-student` = s.`id-student` WHERE passed='Y' AND (data, `id-centre`) = (SELECT MIN(data), e.`id-centre` FROM exams e JOIN centers c ON e.`id-center` = c.`id-center` WHERE e.passed='Y' AND c.`center-name` = 'IT Institute')
```

I am receiving an error like:

```
ER_MIX_OF_GROUP_FUNC_AND_FIELDS: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'sqlPractice.e.id-center'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

According to this post: 
[click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by/23921234)
I want to set a param `sql_mode` in my `docker-compose.yml` because allegedly this will solve a problem.

My `docker-compose.yml` with two params in command flag looks like:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:8
     command: 
       - default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password 
       - sql_mode=""
     volumes:
       - ./mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
       MYSQL_DATABASE: sqlPractice
       MYSQL_USER: admin
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
     ports:
      - '7142:3306'
     security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
```

but after all I am receiving error while launching

```
db_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 363: exec: default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password: not found
```

and after all container is not working properly.

All I want to achieve is configure MySQL instance via `docker-compose.yml` with these two parameters in `command` param in `docker-compose.yml` to make my Query works as it supposes.

I will be grateful for suggestions on how to reach a goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    command: ['--sql_mode=', '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
```

Answer (score 5):

the command should be:

```
--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
--sql_mode=
```

with `--`

and you can not give "" as a value to `--sql_mode` otherwise you will get an error:

```
 Error while setting value '""' to 'sql_mode'
```