# ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
code: 'ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP',
  errno: 1055,
  sqlMessage: "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'fashioncart.items.item_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by",
```

Why do this error comes for?
How can I resolve it?

Comment: update your question add  you query code  .. a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: you can turn off `only_full_group_by` using `SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', ''));`

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 6):

This is related to the annoying 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' default setting in mysql. My advice, permanently switch it off.

mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))

Refer this for more details:
[Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by#36033983)