# Azure MySQL server allow disable 'sql_mode=only_full_group_by'

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have an application that runs on node.js and queries the database hosted on Azure MySQL server, I have encountered an error message during a query with group by

> "...this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by".

Subsequently, I have tried to change my SQL user privilege with

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`

but got an error message:

> Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: change your sql query to fit the  requirements., add columns to your group by or check the cloumns that doesn't work in group by and add aggregation fuctions.

Comment: @nbk Thanks for your reply, but I have too many queries. It's costly to change. If there another method?

Comment: you can check this out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html

Comment: In case using drupal 8 check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/65503455/7995302

Answer (score 7):

You can do this from the "server parameters" in azure portal. You can get the option of sql_mode there. Just change that and save it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-server-parameters

Answer (score 2):

Open Azure portal , navigate to your MySQL server instance , and select "Server Parameters" :

1. Look for "sql_mode" parameter
2. Click on the dropdown menu
3. Unselect "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY"

[image: Azure portal1]