# EF Core Group By is working on sqlite but not SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core-3.1

In case I have the following EF Core statement

```
var totalCallsOnHealthRelatedIssue = await _context.CallReasons
    .Where(cr => cr.Call.IsDeleted != true 
            && (cr.Call.CallStartDateTime >= filterStartDate 
                && cr.Call.CallStartDateTime <= filterEndDate) 
                && cr.Reason.ReasonTypeId == 2)
    .GroupBy(cr => cr.CallId)
    .CountAsync(); // Reason: Any type of health issue is counted ReasonType: Health Issue == 2
```

It is working okay on SQLite but when I change database server to SQL Sever 2019 it does not work.

> Error: Column 'CallReasons.ReasonId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Here is Detail Produced Error

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (152ms) [Parameters=[@__filterStartDate_0='2020-08-01T00:00:00', @__filterEndDate_1='2020-08-25T23:59:59'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM (
          SELECT [c].[CallId], [c].[ReasonId]
          FROM [CallReasons] AS [c]
          INNER JOIN [Calls] AS [c0] ON [c].[CallId] = [c0].[Id]
          INNER JOIN [Reasons] AS [r] ON [c].[ReasonId] = [r].[Id]
          WHERE (([c0].[IsDeleted] <> CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (([c0].[CallStartDateTime] >= @__filterStartDate_0) AND ([c0].[CallStartDateTime] <= @__filterEndDate_1))) AND ([r].[ReasonTypeId] = 2)
          GROUP BY [c].[CallId]
      ) AS [t]
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Infrastructure.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
      Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Column 'CallReasons.ReasonId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__164_0(Task`1 result)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
      ClientConnectionId:294c90c0-ce11-439c-811b-858be9623680
      Error Number:8120,State:1,Class:16
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Column 'CallReasons.ReasonId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__164_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
ClientConnectionId:294c90c0-ce11-439c-811b-858be9623680
Error Number:8120,State:1,Class:16
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action API.Controllers.ReportsController.GetMTHotlineReport (API) in 1260.4704ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'API.Controllers.ReportsController.GetMTHotlineReport (API)'
fail: System.Exception[0]
      Column 'CallReasons.ReasonId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1774.7343ms 500 application/json
```

Comment: There may be a difference in the conversion to SQLite and SQL Server.  What column should be unique ? since you use distinct. You can try `.GroupBy(cr => cr.Property).CountAsync()`

Comment: Exactly, I did using .GroupBy(cr=>cr.CallId). this is working fine on Sqlite but not sql server

Comment: Yes. I do changed and provider

Comment: So I removed all migration file of sqlite then I add package provider for sql server and create new migration.of course I changed connection string.. Then I run project as normal ... But when the querying having groupby ... It is occurring this error... I have no idea why

Comment: Internal Server Error - refreshing the page will make the exception disappear Error. this is front end remark done by me. please see the exception.... this is the iissue " Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Column 'CallReasons.ReasonId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: I tested mysql database. this helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by... but how can I solve with sql server or better way to solve from ef core or code

Comment: have you ever expereienced this or my ef core statement is not proper?

Comment: <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.3"/>

Answer (score 4):

This is one of many issues with `GroupBy` in EF-core 3. A [similar issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21036) is posted on github.

The usual advice is do grouping client-side, i.e. after selecting the required data followed by `AsEnumerable()`. But in this case you only want to count the groups. It would be overkill to pull all data into the client and then do the count.

So you need a work-around. One that I can find is to help EF and explicitly select the grouping column:

```cs
var totalCallsOnHealthRelatedIssue = await _context.CallReasons
    .Where(cr => !cr.Call.IsDeleted 
              && (cr.Call.CallStartDateTime >= filterStartDate 
              && cr.Call.CallStartDateTime <= filterEndDate) 
              && cr.Reason.ReasonTypeId == 2)
    .Select(cr => cr.CallId)
    .GroupBy(id => id)
    .CountAsync();
```

Not pleasant, at all.

But this is a typical example of tunnel vision, focusing to much on working around `GroupBy` issues. In your case you can simply count distinct ids:

```cs
var totalCallsOnHealthRelatedIssue = await _context.CallReasons
    .Where(cr => !cr.Call.IsDeleted 
              && (cr.Call.CallStartDateTime >= filterStartDate 
              && cr.Call.CallStartDateTime <= filterEndDate) 
              && cr.Reason.ReasonTypeId == 2)
    .Select(cr => cr.CallId)
    .Distinct()
    .CountAsync();
```

Comment: This works now!. Can you give me more explaination? am my EF statement wrong?

Comment: No, it's not wrong. It would work in EF6 (not core), it's just that EF core is limited. I'm surprised it works in SQLite.

Comment: Yes this works with SQLite but not sql sever. Such a big surprises

Comment: OK, Sqllite has [different rules for GroupBy syntax](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group-by/), see "SQLite GROUP BY and INNER JOIN clause".

Comment: But is group by EF core really bad for getting data. Something supposed to work but not work. Really frustrating

Comment: Yeah. It's what it is. We can only accept it and try to find work-arounds until they fix things.

Comment: Well, it's even simpler.See the addition.