# How to solve error this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, sql-mode

I made a post today on that but nobody did answer my question.

I'm getting SQL error "this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by".
I did execute this SQL command:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

But it does not work. Error still remains.

I can't adjust every query in the DB because there is are too much of them. I need quick solution.
Is there anybody that is able to help me?

Comment: you don't in a query with ful group by the select query has to have its columns in the Group by or use a aggregation function. btw i have seen this already today

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable ONLY\_FULL\_GROUP\_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by)

Comment: Disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is a bad idea. That will bring you back to the old days of MySQL 5.x when malformed queries were accepted while producing unpredicable results. Stay right where you are, and fix your query.