# Where do I set ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode?

Tags: mysql

Now I'm using PHPMyAdmin on my PHP project. But I have an issue like that:

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'anyc6783_db.exchangerix_exchanges.created' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I am attempting:

```php
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(
    SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,' ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','')
)
```

So, I searched on google and then I get that statement. But where I have to use that statement? config.php or db.php?

If you have experience, please help me.

Comment: Problem is unclear. Error indicates you are in `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode which disallows your invalid aggregate SQL query. Do you want to turn it off? Please note it is highly advised not to turn this MySQL mode off to conform to standard SQL. Fix your aggregate query instead. And post the SQL query for us to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable ONLY\_FULL\_GROUP\_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by)

Comment: what type of hosting you have? decidated? VPS? shared?