# I'm getting MYSQ only_full_group_by Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with my query and mysql throws the following error:

> #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'a.item_name' which is not functionally
> dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
> sql_mode=only_full_group_by

QUERY:

```
SELECT a.item_name,a.discounted_price,                 
               SUM(qty) as total,
               b.date_created
               FROM
               mt_view_order_details as a
               left join mt_order as b
               ON
               a.order_id=b.order_id
               WHERE
               b.date_created BETWEEN '2021-07-03 00:00:00' AND '2021-08-02 23:00:59'
               AND a.merchant_id = '3'
               AND a.status NOT IN ('initial_order')
               GROUP BY item_id
               ORDER BY item_name ASC
```

I'm using a shared hosting, so i can't change sql_mode, please tell me is there any other solution, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`**every** column, that is not in the `GROUP BY` needs to have a [aggregation function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)

So oyu could make

```
SELECT MIN(a.item_name),MIN(a.discounted_price),                 
               SUM(qty) as total,
               MIN(b.date_created)
               FROM
               mt_view_order_details as a
               left join mt_order as b
               ON
               a.order_id=b.order_id
               WHERE
               b.date_created BETWEEN '2021-07-03 00:00:00' AND '2021-08-02 23:00:59'
               AND a.merchant_id = '3'
               AND a.status NOT IN ('initial_order')
               GROUP BY item_id
               ORDER BY item_name ASC
```

or something lie this

```
 SELECT a.item_name,a.discounted_price,                 
           SUM(qty) as total,
           b.date_created
           FROM
           mt_view_order_details as a
           left join mt_order as b
           ON
           a.order_id=b.order_id
           WHERE
           b.date_created BETWEEN '2021-07-03 00:00:00' AND '2021-08-02 23:00:59'
           AND a.merchant_id = '3'
           AND a.status NOT IN ('initial_order')
           GROUP BY item_id,a.item_name,a.discounted_price,b.date_created
           ORDER BY item_name ASC
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it really helped :)

Answer (score -1):

The Error Says

#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'a.item_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

First Expression is `a.item_name`. This means that there is a possibility that a single group may have more than 1 value for column `a.item_name`.

You can solve this in multiple ways:

1. If you are sure that the value in `a.item_name` will be unique for all values in a single group you can use `any_value` aggregate function.

```sql
SELECT any_value(a.item_name), a.discounted_price...
```

2. You can use other aggregate functions like `group_concat`, `sum` etc. if you want to process your data in some other way
3. You can disable sql mode `only_full_group_by`. Check this answer to disable -> [Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by)