# How to keep mysql 5.6 GROUP BY rules on 8.0?

Tags: mysql, sql

With mysql 8.0 the GROUP BY rules got stricter. Is there a way to upgrade to mysql 8.0 without needing to rewrite the queries?

Comment: Some ideas in [this old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23921117/4003419)

Comment: IMO, you should rewrite your queries. The permissive behavior of GROUP BY in old MySQL versions caused invalid results. The new behavior is a good thing.

Comment: I agree, sadly I'm not who decides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `my.cnf` in the section `[mysqld]` add the following:

```
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

And restart MySQL. It will permanently disable the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` feature of MySQL 8.x