# GROUP BY statement throwing errors tutorial isn't

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, group

Hello im going through a tutorial on SQL joins and this statement below is throwing "sql_mode=only_full_group_by" error. I copied this directly from the tutorial and its working for him. Do I just need to disable this mode in the terminal?

```
    SELECT *
    FROM customers
    JOIN orders
            ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
    GROUP BY orders.customer_id;
```

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by url.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Comment: Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & sometimes limited to titles, but read the help. Google re googling/searching, including in Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the `select` list, `HAVING` condition, or `ORDER BY` list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the `GROUP BY` clause nor are functionally dependent on them. [1]

You can disable this, but it really makes sense to leave it enabled. Think about the following case:

```
id | type
---|-----
1  | foo
2  | foo
3  | bar
```

If you used a similar query to yours, `select * from table group by type`, what would you expect the output to be? Perhaps you expect two rows, `foo` and `bar`,  but what do you expect to be in the `id` column, namely for the `foo` record? Should we just choose the earliest record? The latest record? A random record? This is what the error is telling you - instead of having the database engine choose for you, you must be explicit.

So, in your example, you need to think about what the resulting data should look like. Maybe instead of `select *` you want `select customers.name, count(*) ...`, etc.

The reason this works for the tutorial you're following is either they don't have `only_full_group_by` enabled or they're using a MySql version older than 5.7.5 where this was introduced. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, which is probably not what you want.

Finally, if you want your console to behave in the same way your tutorial is behaving, you can disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in the console by:

`mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`

[1] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html