# Group by column and scan into custom struct

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following model. Each instance is part of a group which is only defined as the string `GroupName` here because the actual group is defined in a different service using a different database.

```
type Instance struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID    uint
    Name      string `gorm:"index:idx_name_and_group,unique"`
    GroupName string `gorm:"index:idx_name_and_group,unique"`
    StackName string
    DeployLog string `gorm:"type:text"`
    Preset    bool
    PresetID  uint
}
```

I'd like to scan, the above model, into the following struct. Thus grouping instances why their group name.

```
type GroupWithInstances struct {
    Name      string
    Instances []*model.Instance
}
```

I'm been trying my luck with the following gorm code

```
var result []GroupWithInstances
err := r.db.
    Model(&model.Instance{}).
    Where("group_name IN ?", names).
    Where("preset = ?", presets).
    Group("group_name").
    Scan(&result).Error

indent, _ := json.MarshalIndent(result, "", "  ")
log.Println(string(indent))
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
ERROR: column "instances.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function (SQLSTATE 42803)
```

I'm not sure how to deal with that since I don't want to group by instances but rather their groups.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that your RDBMS is in `Full Group By Mode` - cannot select field that isn't in group by clause or used in an aggregate function (SUM, AVG,...). There are 2 solutions:

1. Disable Full Group By mode. Example in [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by)
2. Modify the query

Even when we go with Solution 1, `gorm` will throw another error about relationship between `GroupWithInstances` and `Instance`.

So I think we should review the feature and go with Solution 1 - only select what is needed.