# Unexplanable behavior of MySQL SUM()

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate

I have a relational db with tables for orders, items, customers and a few linker tables. This query is meant to find the top buyers by sales volume, using MySQL SUM() on the order.grand_total field which is a DECIMAL(8,2). However, the results are very wrong. Here is the query:

```
select c.creation_date, c.id, count(distinct o.id),count(distinct ti.id)
    ,c.first_name, sum(o.grand_total) GrandTotal from mco_customer c 
inner join mco_order o on o.customer_id = c.id and o.status = 'order_paid'
inner join mco_order_line ol on o.id = ol.order_id 
inner join mco_ticket_type tt on tt.id = ol.ticket_type_id
inner join mco_ticket_instance ti on ti.order_line_id = ol.id
group by c.id
ORDER BY COUNT(distinct ti.id) DESC;
```

The top results are:

```
# creation_date, id, count(distinct o.id), count(distinct ti.id), first_name, GrandTotal
'2021-10-09 22:58:43', '565', '3', '103', 'josh', '107598.90'
'2022-10-06 17:24:02', '10609', '16', '56', 'Logan', '7025.79'
'2023-02-11 02:45:03', '14104', '5', '34', 'Stephen', '9261.56'
```

**BUT**, the 3 orders for josh are
12.90, 1075.00, 43.00
so the actual SUM should be 1130.90. Same problem for the other 2 rows where the actual SUM should be much lower and the returned values look more like some strange concatenation.

If I do a query like

```
select sum(grand_total) from mco_order where customer_id=565;
```

Then I get the correct mathematical SUM 1130.90.
It gets worse. If I simplify the query (and eliminate that other info that I really do need) to:

```
select c.creation_date, c.id, count(distinct o.id),count(distinct ti.id)#, count(ti.checkin is not null), c.email, c.last_name, 
    ,c.first_name, sum(o.grand_total) GrandTotal from mco_customer c 
inner join mco_order o on o.customer_id = c.id and o.status = 'order_paid'
inner join mco_order_line ol on o.id = ol.order_id 
group by c.id
ORDER BY GrandTotal DESC;
```

I get different, but also incorrect SUM values

```
# creation_date, id, count(distinct o.id), first_name, GrandTotal
'2021-10-09 22:58:43', '565', '3', 'josh', '3349.70'
'2022-10-06 17:24:02', '10609', '16', 'Logan', '4707.12'
'2023-02-11 02:45:03', '14104', '5', 'Stephen', '5298.90'
```

So now it's multiplying by the number of mco_order rows returned. I'm missing some secret sauce to get the SUM to work correctly

Comment: Aggregate in subquery then join another tables.

Comment: Your query is also invalid and you probably have [only_full_group_by disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by)

Comment: To see what will be aggregated take out the aggregates and group by and see what is returned by the joins